# return muliple values from json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

At the moment, I am using a script that returns a value from json in the format of msg[0].box msg[1].box etc. That is ok if a user enters say 2 items. But what if a user enters more than that. A friend of mine suggested I look at the jquery each function to retun multiple values, but seeing as I am fairly new to jquery, I would be grateful if someone could help me to achieve this using my code.

I am also confused as to why there is no json tab in firebug when the values are returned, just reposnse and html. is this normal? Please note that values are entered using a , as a delimiter.

php code

```
    $dept = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customerdept']);
    $company = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_customer']);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customeraddress']);
    $service = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_service']);
    $box = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_box']);
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['BA_destdate']);
    $destdate = $date -> format('Y-m-d');
    $authorised = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_authorised']);
    $activity = 'New Intake';
    $submit = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['submit']);
    $boxerrortext = 'You must enter a box for intake';

    $array = explode(',', $_POST['BA_box']);

        if (isset($_POST['submit']))   {
          foreach ($array as $box) {


          $form=array('dept'=>$dept,
                 'company'=>$company,
                 'address'=>$address,
                 'service'=>$service,
                 'box'=>$box,
                 'destroydate'=>$destdate,
                 'authorised'=>$authorised,
                 'submit'=>$submit);

          $result[]=$form;

   }  

          echo json_encode( $result );
   }
```

jquery code

```
submitHandler: function()   {
                if ($("#BA_boxform").valid() === true)  { 
                var data = $("#BA_boxform").serialize();
                $.post('/sample/admin/requests/boxes/boxesadd.php', data, function(msg) {
                $("#BA_addbox").html("You have entered box(es): " + "<b>" + msg[0].box + "  " + msg[1].box + "</b><br /> You may now close this window.");
                //console.log(msg[0].box);
                $("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
                }, 'json');

         } else

         { 
           return; 
         }
        },
        success:    function(msg)   {
                //$("#BA_addbox").html("You have entered a box");
                //$("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
        }
```

Comment: There are no JSON tab, cause' response is served with not-a-json response type header (e.g. `text/html` instead of `application/json`) .

Comment: in my cases the json tab is only shown for json-object not for json-array, it seems to have nothing to do with the header type. I do not send any headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is evaluated as an array in javascript from your output. Take a look at the reference : http://www.json.org/

For a demo purpose I've just dummy tested what's the output of your method for more than 2 boxes. So your result from your php script may look like this:

```
 [{
    "dept": "dept",
    "company": "conmpany",
    "address": "address",
    "service": "service",
    "box": "box1",
    "destroydate": "destroydate",
    "authorised": "authorised",
    "submit": "submit"
}, {
    "dept": "dept",
    "company": "conmpany",
    "address": "address",
    "service": "service",
    "box": "box2",
    "destroydate": "destroydate",
    "authorised": "authorised",
    "submit": "submit"
}, {
    "dept": "dept",
    "company": "conmpany",
    "address": "address",
    "service": "service",
    "box": "box3",
    "destroydate": "destroydate",
    "authorised": "authorised",
    "submit": "submit"
}]
```

On javascript side this is processed as an array of objects. Since is a standard array a `for` loop would be sufficient to retrieve the values, therefore your method may look like this:

```
$.post('/sample/admin/requests/boxes/boxesadd.php', data, function(msg) {
                var messageOutput = '';
                for (var i = 0; i<msg.length; i++){
                    messageOutput += msg[i].box+'  ';     
                }
                $("#BA_addbox").html("You have entered box(es): " + "<b>" + messageOutput + "</b><br /> You may now close this window.");
                //console.log(msg[0].box);
                $("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
            }, 'json');
```

Ofcourse you can use `$.each` function but is not always a solution to use the bulldozer when just a shovel is required.

As for the json output in firebug is already there starting with the version 1.4a11 : http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/json-explorer-for-firebug/

[image: json tab on firebug]

Answer (score 3):

On how to use `$.each` function...

```
var html = "You have entered box(es): <b>"
$.each(msg, function(index, element) { 
    if(index > 0)
         html += " ";
    html += element.box;
});
html += "</b><br /> You may now close this window."
```

Comment: Where would I place my div to show the message as in my code: #BA_addbox. Many thanks

Comment: For example. if i place here:  var html = $("#BA_addbox").html("You have entered box(es): <b>") then only message is shown and no items.

Comment: Can you correct where I have gone wrong. should it be withing the if function? Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I shall post a new topic in relation to my question. thanks

Comment: @user1532468 In my code, I've created a variable named `html` and placed here a string and then concatenated some other strings to it. In your code variable `html` contains a jQuery object, which holds a reference to DOM element with id BA_addbox, cause' `.html("...")` just places passed text inside of a DOM element and returns a jQuery object, so you can do things like `$('#BA_addbox').html('string').addClass('myClazz').css('color', 'red');`